# Is $A\cap B = A \Leftrightarrow (A\cap B)^{c} = A^{c}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\cap B = A \Leftrightarrow (A\cap B)^{c} = A^{c}$

Is it allowed to modify both sides of this equation by complementing both sides?

Comment: In all cases, if $(\text{thing }1) = (\text{thing }2)$, and $f$ is a well defined function, then $f(\text{thing }1) = f(\text{thing }2)$. And complementation is reversible because $(A^c)^c = A$.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you!